# Limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin\left(\pi\cos^2(x)\right)}{x^2}$

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

Could someone help me solve this limit without L'Hopital's rule?
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin\left(\pi\cos^2(x)\right)}{x^2}
$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the identity $\sin(x)=\sin(\pi-x)$ and then multiply and divide by the argument of $\sin$.

Comment: Thanks a lot man for helping and not just giving the answer. I got it.